# Center content of frame in beamer class

Tags: beamer

Doesn't it bother anybody that the beamer class doesn't perfectly center the contents of frames vertically?

There is a bit more space below than above. Could anybody provide a solution on how to achieve a perfectly centered content and, more importantly, to make this the global setting?

Below is a (trivial) MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        This text is not perfectly centered vertically.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`textpos` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) lets you put your text at any position you specify on the page. In `beamer` class, the package must be loaded with the `overlay` option, this is not the case in other document classes. I also turned on the `showboxes` option just to compare with the perfect center calculated by `tikz`. In your final document, you can remove the `showboxes` option, or, add the `\textblockrulecolor{white}` command to hide the boxes. The latter command in my experience resulted in a more accurate positioning. But I have no idea why this was the case.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,lmodern}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay,showboxes]{textpos}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{frame}{title}
  This text is not perfectly centered vertically.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw (current page.north west)--(current page.south east) (current page.south west)--(current page.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{textblock}{13.5}[.5,.5](8,8)
    This text is perfectly centered vertically and horizontally.
  \end{textblock}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your main question, although I suspect that there are some hidden "margins" for titles, headers, footers, etc. which are not seen on an empty frame. In any case, if you insist in having some text perfectly centered, you can always use `TiKZ`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
        This text is not perfectly centered vertically.
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture] \node[anchor=center,draw] at (current page.center) {This text is perfectly centered vertically and horizontally.};
        \draw (current page.north west)--(current page.south east) (current page.south west)--(current page.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think that this provides a proper solution to my problem. Like this I would have to put a `tikzpicture` environment inside each of my frames. What I am looking for is something to put in the preamble so that it works globally on all frames and every kind of content (I don't know if I could put **anything** inside a tikzpicture environment).